# Type-Token Ratio in Google Sheets: How to manipulate long strings of text (millions of characters)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, nlp, array-formulas, typetoken

Here’s the challenge. In a Google Sheets spreadsheet, I have a column in which can be found a range of cells containing lists of words separated by comas, one per row, up to a thousand row. Each list show the words taken from a text, in alpha-numeral order, from a few hundred to a few thousand words. I need to count both the total of words in all the rows, taken together, and the number of unique word forms too. In other words, from the glossary of natural language processing, I want to know the number of *tokens* and the number of *types* in my corpus, in order to calculate the *type-token ratio* or lexical density.

In particular, finding the number of unique word forms in the whole column have proven to be a challenge. In an ARRAY FORMULA, with corresponding functions, I’ve JOINED the strings, SPLITED the words, TRANSPOSED them, then removed duplicates with UNIQUE function, then counted the remaining word forms. This worked on a sample corpus constituted of a little over ten lists of words, but failed when I reached fifteen or so lists of words taken together, a far cry from the thousand lists I need to join in my formula to obtain the results I am looking for.

From what I can gather, the problem would reside in that the resulting string I intend to manipulate is exceeding 50,000 characters. Here and there, for specific cases, I’ve found similar questions, and propositions for workarounds, mostly through custom functions, but I could not replicate the result. Needless to say, writing custom fonctions on my own is beyond my reach. Someone suggests to use QUERY headers, but I did not figured either if this was of any help in my case.

The formulas I came up with are the following:

To obtain the total number of words (tokens) through all the lists:
`=COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN(",";1;B2:B);",")))`

To obtain the number of unique word forms (types) through all the lists:
`=COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";1;B2:B);",")))))`

[A sample in a spreadsheet can be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GzgReYGiDtgkbS9bf0biudgJS0J4tAhraNqWTKH-O98/edit?usp=sharing).

EDIT 1:

I’ve included the column of texts stripped of ponctuation, from which the lists of words are generated, and the formula used to generate them.

EDIT 2:

Changed the title to better reflect the general intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For total items, try:

```
=arrayformula(query(flatten(iferror(split(B2:B;",";1);));"select count(Col1) where Col1 !='' label count(Col1) '' ";0))
```

For total unique items:

```
=arrayformula(query(unique(flatten(iferror(split(B2:B;",";1);)));"select count(Col1) where Col1 !='' label count(Col1) '' ";0))
```

You might get problems if you have too many rows in the sheet. If so, set the range limit to something like B2:B1000

Add this to cell C1 to get a list of 'Comma separated items':

```
=arrayformula({"Comma separated items";if(B2:B<>"";len(regexreplace(B2:B;"[^\,]";))+1;)})
```

**Explanation:**

The `arrayformula()` allows the calculation to cascade down the sheet, from one cell.

So within the `arrayformula()`, the starting point is the `split(B2:B;",")` to create columns for each of the comma separated items.

The `iferror(split(B2:B;",");"")` leaves a blank where cells don't have a comma (like those from row 32). Instead of `;"")` shown above I usually just use `;)`, removing `""` so nothing is the result of the iferror.

Then `flatten()` takes all of the columns and flattens them into a single column.

`query()` is needed to count the resulting column `count(Col1)` where no cells are empty `where Col1 !=''`, and the `label count(Col1) ''` removea a label 'count' which would usually be displayed.

For the list of unique values, `unique()` is placed before the`query()`, after the `flatten()`.

Comment: Aresvik, you sir have just resolved my challenge it seems! And in an elegant way, which I much prefer. I am much grateful for that. Let me double check with the full lists. could you explain briefly what is happening here?

Comment: Explanation added - let me know if it's not clear :)

Comment: I might have some more reading to do, but it’s all good. Thank you again Aresvik. The single array formula for the partial count of word occurrences is great too! Thank you also for that.

Comment: Aresvik, the array formula you offered to populate the column of partial totals of word occurrences, per row, has inspired my to try and tweak further my table. I’ve been trying for the last couple of hours to do something similar with the previous column in the table: the column containing the texts from which the lists of words are generated. Unfortunately, I haven’t yet found the way have it work. By any chance... I’ve edit the spreadsheet to had a sample of this column, and replaced the lists of words with the formula that generates them. Would you be so kind and have another look at it?

Comment: Sure thing. What do you expect the result to be? Can you provide specifics in the sheet?

Comment: For the result, in each row, same as it appears in column B in the spreadsheet. But instead of a formula in each row, working the magic of a single array formula filing the rows under all the way down, like you did for column C.

Comment: Looking at your sample sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GzgReYGiDtgkbS9bf0biudgJS0J4tAhraNqWTKH-O98/edit#gid=0), is it important to have colB? Cell `C1` can work off Col A: `=arrayformula({"Items";if(A2:A<>"";len(regexreplace(A2:A;"[^\ ]";))+1;)})` as can cell `G2`: `=arrayformula(query(flatten(iferror(split(A2:A;" ";1);));"select count(Col1) where Col1 !='' label count(Col1) '' ";0))` and cell `G3`: `=arrayformula(query(unique(flatten(iferror(split(A2:A;" ";1);)));"select count(Col1) where Col1 !='' label count(Col1) '' ";0))`

Comment: Great suggestion, adopted! I’ve retooled the table, and will be counting tokens and types from the cleaned text column (A). Still, for an ulterior purpose, I would like to have the words of each texts listed in alpha-numeral order. If there is a way to do it with an elegant array formula, I’ld be a taker still.

Comment: You had me thinking I might be able to count the subtotals and totals of words occurrences (items, tokens) and unique word forms (types) from the uncleaned texts directly, doing the cleaning in the same formula. I did the subtotal of word occurrences per row, and the total of word occurrences per whole column, but I am failing right now to obtain the same result for the total of unique word forms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237750/discussion-between-archilecteur-and-aresvik).